# SQL server 2012 - Query on retrieving matching records from a table by cross checking with two other tables

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables (say A,B and C) with same column names and datatype. And these tables can be joined using four unique columns, say name,company,Seq_Number and role. Now I want to select records of particular role from table A and cross check them with the records in Table B and C.If they do not exist in both the tables, then we need to deactivate/remove those records from Table A. The problem is, the records which does not exist in table B might exist in Table C. So, I need to remove the records of particular role only if they don't exist in both B & C tables. I tried with the below query. But it is not returning the expected result. Kindly help me on this

```
SELECT DISTINCT FAT_Cust.name
              , FAT_Cust.Company
              , FAT_Cust.role
              , FAT_Cust.Seq_Number
              , Cust.name
              , Cus.Company
              , Cust.role
              , Cust.Seq_Numberfrom (
    SELECT DISTINCT ALC.NAME, ALC.Company, ALC.ROLE, ALC.Seq_Number
    FROM AL_Customer ALC
    INNER JOIN BL_Customer LPC ON ALC.NAME = LPC.NAME
        AND ALC.Company = LPC.Company
        AND ALC.ROLE = LPC.ROLE
        AND ALC.Seq_Number = LPC.Seq_Number
        AND ALC.Record_Active = 1

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT ALC.NAME, ALC.Company, ALC.ROLE, ALC.Seq_Number
    FROM AL_Customer ALC
    INNER JOIN CL_Customer CLC ON ALC.NAME = CLC.NAME
        AND ALC.Company = CLC.Company
        AND ALC.ROLE = CLC.ROLE AND ALC.Seq_Number = CLC.Seq_Number
        AND ALC.Record_Active = 1
) Cust
RIGHT OUTER JOIN AL_Customer FAT_Cust ON FAT_Cust.NAME = Cust.NAME
    AND FAT_Cust.Company = Cust.Company
    AND FAT_Cust.ROLE = Cust.ROLE
    AND FAT_Cust.Seq_Number = Cust.Seq_Number
    AND FAT_Cust.Record_Active = 1
WHERE Cust.NAME IS NULL
    AND Cust.Company IS NULL
    AND Cust.ROLE IS NULL
    AND Cust.Seq_Number IS NULL
    AND Cust.ROLE < > 'OWN'
```

Comment: what about inner Join between 3 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the query given below

```
SELECT ALC.* FROM AL_Customer ALC
    LEFT JOIN BL_Customer BPC ON ALC.NAME = BPC.NAME
        AND ALC.Company = BPC.Company
        AND ALC.ROLE = BPC.ROLE
        AND ALC.Seq_Number = BPC.Seq_Number
        AND ALC.Record_Active = 1 
        AND BLC.Record_Active = 1

    LEFT JOIN CL_Customer CPC ON ALC.NAME = CPC.NAME
        AND ALC.Company = CPC.Company
        AND ALC.ROLE = CPC.ROLE
        AND ALC.Seq_Number = CPC.Seq_Number
        AND ALC.Record_Active = 1 
        AND CLC.Record_Active = 1
WHERE ALC.Record_Active = 1 
AND (BPC.NAME IS NULL) 
AND (CPC.NAME IS NULL)
```

you can add more condition is where class to narrow down the matching criteria. the above query is assuming that name is present for all the records in the table. I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Midhun. It is really helpful. I have one more query too.. I have 3 tables A, B and C as mentioned in the above scenario and they have 9 common columns between them. Table A has 2 types of records from both table B & C and also few records which are

Comment: Thanks Midhun. It is really helpful. I have one more query too.. I have 3 tables A, B and C as mentioned in the above scenario and they have 9 common columns between them. Table A has 2 types of records 1. Records from table B or C 2. records which are not from table B & C. Now I want to compare only those records in table A which are from table in B & C with records in table B & C based on those 9 common columns. There might be difference in data of one common column between the records in table A & (table B or C). I want to pick that particular record only. Kindly help me on this

Comment: Example: table A
ID_Number company Role Seq_Number FirstName MiddleName LastName Gender DOB
1234 12 OWN 1 Test1 mid1 last1 F 1979-01-26
Table B or C
ID_Number company Role Seq_Number FirstName MiddleName LastName Gender DOB
1234 12 OWN 1 Test1 mid1 last1 F 1990-08-30
In the above example, each of the above common column is compared with each other. Only the column DOB differs. Hence I have to report this record. Likewise, if the data in any of this common column mismatches, I need to fetch those records. Please help me in getting this done

Comment: SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA Ta LEFT JOIN TableB Tb ON <matching columns from TableA and TableB> LEFT JOIN TableC Tc ON <matching columns from TableA and TableC> WHERE (Tb.<primarykey / unique column> is null) or (Tc.<primarykey / unique column> is null). If you can give me the table script, i will be able to write the exact query. Otherwise please understand the theme from the generic query.